# Trigger update the rest of the table values once one attribute has been populated

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I want to make a trigger that would populate the rest of the values in the table once one attribute has been inserted.

So once a date has been inserted, I need the trigger to fill out the rest of the columns.

```
CREATE TABLE dim_date 
(
    Date_Id INTEGER
        CONSTRAINT date_id_pk PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
    CalendarDate DATE NOT NULL,
    CalendarYear VARCHAR (20),
    CalendarQuarter VARCHAR (20),
    CalendarMonth VARCHAR (20),
    CalendarMonthNumber SMALLINT,
    CalendarDateNumber SMALLINT,
    CalendarYearNumber SMALLINT,
    CalendarQuarterNumber CHAR(1),
    CalendarWeek SMALLINT,
    CalendarWeekdayNumber Char(1),
    CalendarWeekday VARCHAR (20),
    CalendarWeekNumber SMALLINT,
    CalendarHalf CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO dim_date (CalendarDate) 
VALUES ('2018-07-26'),
       ('2017-05-02'),
       ('2015-09-10'),
       ('2017-04-23');

CREATE TRIGGER trg_date ON dim_date
FOR INSERT
AS 
    UPDATE dim_date 
    SET CalendarYear = (SELECT YEAR(CalendarDate) FROM INSERTED)
    WHERE -- not sure how to proceed from here
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to use a properly relational, set-based approach - by **joining** to the `Inserted` pseudo table, and set the date part information for those newly inserted rows.

Something along the lines of this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_date 
ON dim_date
FOR INSERT
AS 
    UPDATE dd
    SET CalendarYear = YEAR(dd.CalendarDate),
        CalendarQuarter = DATEPART(Quarter, dd.CalendarDate),
        CalendarMonthNumber = MONTH(dd.CalendarDate)
        -- and so on, for all the other DATEPART pieces you need

    FROM dim_date dd
    -- join on the primary key to update all rows that were newly inserted only
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON dd.Date_Id = i.Date_Id 
GO
```

Now you just need to fill in the remaining date parts you need to determine - check the [official MS documentation on `DATEPART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for insights!